# How do I replace the value of a specific xml tag with the hashed value?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have several zipped xml files which contain transactions stored in `Trans` xml tags. Some of these transactions (not all!) contain a `<customer>` xml tag which includes a `custnumber` xml tag. I need to anonymize this customer number in the xml file in order to use the xml file for development purposes. The structure of the xml is something like this:

```
<transactions>
  <trans>
  ...
    <customer>
    ...
      <customer_custnumber>123456789</customer_custnumber>
    ...
    </customer>
    ...
  </tran>
</transactions>
```

Because of my downstream processes I need to preserve the maximum length of the customer number when I hash it. For this I wrote a tool using java which hashes the customer number to a unique hash in a certain range of digits.

My first approach was to use read all customer numbers from the xml file and on every occurence I invoked my hash tool. This took way to long as I was calling the java tool like 5000 times per file resulting in a runtime of 5-6 minutes per file (I have >40 files per day).

My seconds approach was to extract all customer numbers in the order they occur in the xml file using `zgrep` and `awk`, write them to a text file and run my java tool to hash every line of the file. This is significantly faster as it took only several seconds for 5000 numbers. But now my problem is to replace the original value of the customer number with the hashed value from the text file. I know they are in order, so the first occurence in the xml file relates to the first hash in the text file and so on. But how do I replace this now?

Here is my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

tempFile=cardNumber_tmp.txt
hashedTempFile=hashed_cardNumber_tmp.txt

for file in ${DIR_SRC}/input.xml.zip ; do
    declare listOfIds
    listOfIds=$(zgrep "<customer_custnumber>" $file | awk -F">" '{print $2}' | awk -F"<" '{print $1}') 
    # $listOfIds contains all Ids separated whitespaces
    # use tr to replace whitespace with newline 
    echo $listOfIds | tr " " "\n" > ${DIR_TEMP}/${tempFile} 
    # call HashCustNumber.jar for tempFile with type customer
    java -jar HashCustNumber.jar "${DIR_TEMP}/${tempFile}" "customer"
    # HashCustNumber.jar writes result into $hashedTempFile
    declare -a arr
    readarray -t arr < "${DIR_TEMP}/${hashedTempFile}"
    # Array arr contains Hashes without newline

    # ??

done

# delete tempFiles
rm ${DIR_TEMP}/${tempFile} 
rm ${DIR_TEMP}/${hashedTempFile}
```

I also read that I shouldn't use sed or awk to extract data from xml files and I'm not able to use xmlstarlet as it is not installed on my company server. Any ideas how to replace the values with the hashes values in a way which does not involve thousands of calls of the hashing program?

Comment: Can I assume customer numbers are unique?  Then modify your java output a bit to: `customer-number:hash_value`, one per line.  Then loop on these lines, cut on the `:` and replace the customer-number by the has_value using sed or awk.  Yes it is preferable to not use these when dealing with XML, but if you do not have access to XML parser tools, it's the best you can do.  But if you are "fluent" in Java, why not do the whole thing in Java then?  XML parsers exist in Java, it might be simpler for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the hash function was written in java the more efficient would be to do the whole process in java using zip api and jaxp/sax.

Otherwise what was expensive is to launch a jvm for each id. Also zgrep is just a script using gzip and grep, and should not work with `.zip` files.

- first unzip, to a working directory, re-zip at the end
- then asuming your list of ids is in a file `"$num_file"` and the file to modify *unzipped* is `"$xml_file"` and target file `"$new_xml_file"` ; replacement could be done with following perl command

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN{
            $num_file = shift @ARGV;
            {
                local @ARGV = $num_file;
                @ids = map {chomp;$_} <>;
            }
        }
        s/<customer_custnumber>\K[^<]*/shift @ids/e
' "$num_file" "$xml_file" > "$new_xml_file"
```

Note knowing that previous awk command was used to extract numbers it is "***as***" safe because perl uses the same expression

Comment: I swiched to java completely, as you suggested. It is not really fast due to the zipping and unziping, but fast enough in the end to be useable. The java program takes the zip file, replaces the values and writes a new zip file.